# Requesting focus in a child component from an external library with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

**Edit - Solved**

TL;DR: Do not set a `focusable` modifier on a `BasicTextView` or any of the children inside of the `decoratorBox` that are parents of the `innerTextField`.

The key here was that focus was getting set and passed back through all of the callbacks but not getting set into the `innerTextField` of the `BasicTextField`. In the library, they are modifying the parent `BasicTextField` to have the `focusRequester` and be focusable, so when requesting focus, the focus is getting stopped at the parent and not passed into the `innerTextField`. This explains why the callbacks were working fine as well; manually focusing the `innerTextField` was passing the `focusState` back to its parent which was then firing the callback just fine. Unfortunately this means that I can't use this component from this library, but by copying the component into my project (our company wrote it) and removing the `focusable` modifier, focus is now getting passed to the `innerTextField`, the keyboard is showing, and all is well with the world.

**The Setup**

I am in the process of migrating an existing application from XML to Compose. Our app was originally created by some talented Node developers undertaking their first Android application, so we are taking this opportunity to apply knowledge from some experienced devs new to the team and hard lessons learned. It's very important to me that we don't introduce significant debt or use Hacks™️ to achieve our goals.

**The Challenge**

We have a library of styled components built by another team that we are *strongly* encouraged to use in our application. Generally the benefit of not having to worry about styling *most* of the time outweighs any gripes. Right now, I am working on a fairly straight-forward bottom sheet that has one text input and two buttons on it. Easy!

Component hierarchy looks something like:

```
MainScreen
  -> ModalBottomSheetLayout (from Material Compose)
    -> MainContent (the main content that the bottom sheet pops over)
    -> BottomSheetContent
      -> CustomTextInputComponent (from external library)
        -> InternalTextField (internal to library)
          -> BasicTextField (from Compose Core)
```

The way they have this setup, you are supposed to pass the `FocusRequester` and an `onFocusChanged` callback into the `CustomTextInputComponent` as arguments which then get passed to the `InternalTextField` as arguments and eventually set into the modifier of the `BasicTextView`.

```
modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .align(Alignment.CenterStart)
    .then(if (focusRequester != null) Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester) else Modifier)
    .focusable(true)
    .onFocusChanged {
        onFocusChanged(it)
    }
```

My `BottomSheetContent` looks something like:

```
@Composable
fun BottomSheetContent(
    onContinue: (String) -> Unit,
    onCancel: () -> Unit
) {
    val textField by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    val showDebugToast by remember { mutableStateOf(false) } 

    Column {
        CustomTextInputComposable(
            modifier = Modifier...
            text = textField,
            onTextChanged = { textFieldValue ->
                textField = textFieldValue
            },
            onFocusChanged = { hasFocus ->
                showDebugToast = hasFocus
            },
            focusRequester = focusRequester
        )
        CustomButton(
            text = "Cancel"
        ) {
            onCancel()
        }
        CustomButton(
            text = "Continue"
        ) {
            onContinue(textField.text)
        }
        if (showDebugToast) {
            CustomToast(message = "HAS FOCUS!! ※\(^o^)/※", type = ToastType.SUCCESS)
        }
    }
}
```

**Where I'm Stuck**

I'm trying to set focus to the text input when the bottom sheet shows.  The one text input in the bottom sheet is the only text input on the screen. I do know that `onFocusChanged` is getting called back from the correct spot, because when I manually touch in the text field, the callback fires all the way back to `BottomSheetContent` and the toast displays.

I do not know how to signal to the `BasicTextField` to ask for focus programmatically. I have tried everything in my (*fried*) brain and all ideas from a few hours of Googling in my `BottomSheetContent`, namely:

- Calling `focusRequester.requestFocus()` from **everywhere**. I've called it from the click listener of one of my buttons. I've tried many of the commonly prescribed side-effect approaches, with and without delays, at the top, bottom, and everywhere in-between:

```
LaunchedEffect(focusRequester) {
    focusRequester.requestFocus()
}
```

```
LocalView.current.viewTreeObserver.addOnWindowFocusChangeListener {
    if (it) focusRequester.requestFocus()
}
```

```
val windowInfo = LocalWindowInfo.current

LaunchedEffect(windowInfo) {
    snapshotFlow { windowInfo.isWindowFocused }.collect { isWindowFocused ->
        if (isWindowFocused) {
            focusRequester.requestFocus()
        }
    }
}
```

- I tried moving the `focusRequester` out to the `MainScreen` to request focus after the bottom sheet shows and everywhere else I could think of there.
- I even copied the two composables from the library and modified them to see what I could find. I tried setting the `focusRequester` directly on everything that would accept it in both of the library composables, including everything inside of the `decorationBox` on the `BasicTextField`. I could not find the composable that gained focus when I touched the input manually.

**Final Thoughts**

I suspect the real problem here is two-fold: `focusRequester.requestFocus()` doesn't behave the way that I expect, and I can't identify that composable that gains focus when I touch the text input. The one thing that I can verify is that when I do grab focus manually with a touch, calling `focusRequester.requestFocus()` pulls focus away. I have triple-checked that I am not setting it as the focus requester on any other composables, and I traced it through the library to verify that they are only setting it to the one composable as well.

I'm fully stumped if there **is** a way to do this, and I'm on to wondering if the `CustomTextInputComposable` is a lost cause. Genuinely, nothing would make me happier than finding out that there is something that I am just fundamentally misunderstanding about the whole thing. Hoping you all will set me straight.